# É possível retorna todos ids de uma busca do elasticsearch mantendo o `size` especificado?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

É possível retorna todos ids de uma busca do elasticsearch?

Tenho a seguinte query que na maioria das vezes retorna no campo `['hits']['total']` mais hits do que o que especifico no `size`.

Como no exemplo:

```
query_body = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query": 'caderno preto',
                        "fields":[
                            "DescricaoSEO",
                            "TermoBusca",
                            "Fabricante"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"100%",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": []
        }
    }
}
```

Minha query retorna os 40 primeiros hits, mas quando imprimo o total de hits tenho:

```
print(retornoES['hits']['total'])
{'value': 426, 'relation': 'eq'}
```

Existe alguma forma de retorna todos os 426 `_id` na consulta mantendo o `size` dos 40 primeiros?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algumas pesquisas consegui monta a seguinte query.

```
GET meuindex/_search
{
   "from":0,
   "size":40,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"pincel branco bic",
                  "fields":[
                     "DescricaoSEO",
                     "TermoBusca",
                     "Fabricante",
                     "Codigo"
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match":"100%"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "Codigo Filter":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"Codigo.keyword",
            "size":10000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Isso me retorna uma agregação dos meus códigos que são o mesmo do campo _id

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]